# What JWT Tokens should be stored for use later?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, amazon-cognito, jwt

I am looking at implemented Cognito for user login and would like to understand the process of validating JWT's a little better.

The application in question is on asp.net 4.5 MVC and not related to .NET Core. The only information on AWS Cognito I can find online relates to .NET core.

I understand the meaning of each token type as documented here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token

I also understand the required steps in validating a JWT:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html

My question is which JWT needs to be validated and at what stage?

Example 1.
A user logs in, once logged in they are returned with an Access, ID and Refresh token.
**Do all of the tokens need to be validated at this point or just the Access token?**

Is the refresh token only validated before trying to use it (in order to gain new access and ID tokens)?
OR should all tokens be validated on any authorised content request?

**What tokens should be stored in the FormsAuthentication Cookie for use later?** We are using the standard `[Authorize]` pattern in asp.net.

Answer (score 3):

**Question:** Do all of the tokens need to be validated at this point or just the Access token?

**Answer:**
Validation is always done on Access token only.

Refresh token itself need not be validated. It is merely used for the purpose of obtaining fresh set of ID token and Access token.

**Question:**  What tokens should be stored in the FormsAuthentication Cookie for use later?

**Answer:** This is specific to implementation. There is no rule on what token must be saved.

If the requirement is to just know the user's email or phone number, then just the ID token can be saved.

If the requirement is to allow one-time access for up an hour for the user,
then storing just the access token is sufficient.

If the requirement is to allow user to access the resource for up to 30 days, without being prompted for password, then refresh token must be saved.

Comment: Thanks @Gopinath. The requirement is for the user to remain logged in for the length of time the access token is available until (IDP configuration dependant). Therefore should we save the access token? Further more, do we need to validate that token on every `[Authorize]` page request or do we only validate it when receiving the token from the IDP initially?

Comment: Thanks, @StuartM. In this case of allowing the user to remain logged in for the length of access token, only the Access token token must be saved and validated for every inbound request made from UI to back-end. The token can be saved in two ways - Either as a cookie, or as the embedded 'Authorization Header'(commonly referred as Bearer token). The back-end will have to validate the token, picked either from cookie or from the authorization header, for every inbound request coming from UI. This secures whole user journey and also makes it easy to prompt the user to login when token expires.

Comment: thanks, should the expiration of the cookie be set to the expiry date/time from the access token? Should I protect against that being changed, for security reasons, validate the token and check the expiry date on that instead??

Comment: Yes, Stuart. You are right. Setting the expiry of cookie to match that of the token is a good practice. It will enhance the security and also reduce unnecessary calls to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to validate the access token as it includes both authentication and authorization. You should be validating access token prior to providing access to protected resources.

The id token contains claims (information) of the authenticated user. It can be used for verification as well but there is more power in using access tokens as you can create scopes to define permissions and roles. Access token is also the input to many of Cognito APIs user operations.

AWS Cognito follows OpenID Connect Protocol which is built on top of Oauth2 for which these terminologies originate from.

The refresh token is a long lived token to retrieve newer short lived tokens (id token, access token). Currently with Cognito's implementation, shorter lived tokens expire every 1 hour and refresh tokens are configurable in the user pool. In the case where a refresh token becomes invalid/expired, attempts to retrieve newer short lived tokens will fail therefore you do not need to validate refresh token yourself.

You can store the refresh token (in some sort of session) to assist with the retrieval of new access, id tokens without re-authentication. You can also store the access token so that the refresh token is used only once per hour (when the access token expires) to prevent issuance of unnecessary tokens and round-trips to Cognito. The id token storage is really up to your use case, if you were interested in keeping the user claims (user information stored in the JWT of id token).